# Iterate - Raster Calculator - 8 Day MODIS LST to Monthly Avg

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, raster-calculator, modis, iterator

I have 8-day MODIS Land Surface Temperature data from 2009-2013. I have used Model Builder to extract the LST_day and LST_Night Subdatasets (in different model runs). What I am attempting to do next is take 3, 8-day TIFFS (combined, a month of data) and average them so it comes out to be 1 monthly avg. TIFF for each month from 2009 to 2013. I am unsure how I can select specific 8-day data to average in raster calculator using iterator - is there a way to specify or only select certain data? Is there a way to do this in ArcPy?

This is my current model: [image]

Comment: I would also like to add raster calculator after extract subdataset in order to multiply by the scale factor of .02, but it will not allow me to connect the tools...

Answer (score 1):

In your question you say you have already extracted subsets of data (day and night) but your screen shot shows a model where you are extracting a subset so it is not clear what the intended inputs are.

There is a tool in Spatial Analyst called [Cell Statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z0000007q000000) that would be a simpler approach for computing an average value for a cell over a set of rasters.

You would need to create a raster iterator to [collect](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//004000000005000000) the rasters into a list. This would be a sub-model within a model that has the cell statistics tool. If you are unfamiliar with sub-models then look at the Help file [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002w0000007p000000).

Comment: Sorry, Let me be more precise in my question. So the Complete model I am aiming for it [Iterate Raster] --> [Extract Subdataset] --> [Raster Calculator: multiply each image by .02] --> [Project Raster] --> [Extract by Mask] --> [Raster Calculator: choosing 3 Tiffs from a year file of 8-day LST data to average into monthly Tiffs] Is it possible to do all of this within one model?

Comment: Was there an answer to this? I have the same problem.